# SecureSocial play 2.3

Tags: java, playframework-2.3, securesocial

I use SecureSocial **only** for the part **Facebook Connect (OAuth2..)**

Indeed, with SecureSocial 2.1.4, I did **manually** :

- read **sessionId** in the cookie
- call the authenticator store plugin to find the **userId from sessionId**
- find my user in DB.

Now, on master :

- I managed to get the authenticator with the sessionId ( through **CookieAuthenticatorBuilder** has there is no more plugins, and the equivalent: **authenticatorService**, has a **private** access in RuntimeEnvironment )
- the Authenticator no longer contains a userId but a reference to the **user**, which is **private**.

-> I am stuck here. I'd like some feedback on what I'm doing and some idea to retrieve my user from the authenticator.

Thanks !

Comment: I rather think about javascript facebook connect ... It becomes soo complicated to customize when it's so easy in JS

Comment: Why do you want to read the id from the cookie yourself? SecureSocial does all that for you. The idea is that if the user is authenticated you will get a reference to it in the request (eg: request.user).  Did you see the sample apps?

Comment: I need to log the user on demand. Is it possible ?  (By the way, thank you for your awesome module ! )

Comment: If you want to log the user in programmatically use the AuthenticatorService. Look in the Registration controller how it is used to log the user automatically after registration: https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/3.0-M1/module-code/app/securesocial/controllers/Registration.scala#L193